# App Background issue While in Background

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

My app is checking some algorithm in the background, after something like 30 minutes 
my application seems to be like close (iphone turn to sleep mode i think). I need the app
to run this algorithm as long as it is in the background.

Do you have any idea how to set this 20 minutes timer to recount by some action?
maybe `NSRunloop` or something else?

Comment: I think currently you have to be an audio application, VOIP application or location aware application to have any chance of running when the phone is "asleep". There have been apps that tried to use silent audio to circumvent this issue but that has been rejected by apple.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reset this timer or continue to run  in the background on a stock OS iPhone (except for a limited amount of time, or if your is legitimately of 3 types, VoIP, audio or GPS).

The user can reset this timer by bringing your app to the foreground, perhaps after a notification or something.